# joomla admin in subdomain blank page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, joomla, virtualhost, wampserver

I am having trouble accessing the Joomla administrator page in a subdomain.

Here's what it's like, the site is http://test.com and the admin page must be http://admin.test.com

I am using a WAMP server with virtual host enabled.

here's my httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@test.com
    DocumentRoot "c:\wamp\www\test"
    ServerName test.com
    ServerAlias www.test.com
    ErrorLog "C:\wamp\www\test\logs\error.log"
    CustomLog "C:\wamp\www\test\logs\access.log" common
       <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/test">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Deny,Allow   
        Allow from all 
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@test.com
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\test\administrator"
    ServerName admin.test.com
    ServerAlias www.admin.test.com
    ErrorLog "C:\wamp\www\test\logs\error.log"
    CustomLog "C:\wamp\www\test\logs\access.log" common
        <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/test/administrator">
        AllowOverride All
        Order Deny,Allow   
        Allow from all 
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

test.com works fine, but the admin doesn't. It only displays a white blank page. I also noticed that the redirection works in admin since the page title loads the admin page title.

I'm using Joomla! 3.4.4 Stable, and WAMP Server with Apache/2.4.9 and PHP 5.5.12.

Answer (score 0):

In your configuration.php file under your Joomla website, set $error_reporting to "maximum". This will show you what the error really is and will give you pinpoints on how to fix it.